# Cannot map through AsyncStorage data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I try to build  react-native app with AsyncStorage with multiGet property. I can sucessfully add stuff to storage, and even display it in debugger console.log but when I want to map through array of data, it constantly shows no result. Does anyone knows where is the problem?

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this._getAllData();
  }

  _getAllData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = [];
      const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      const items = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
        stores.map((result, i, store) => {
          // let key = store[i][0];
          let value = store[i][1];
          let parsedValue = JSON.parse(value);
          data.push(parsedValue);
        });

        this.setState({ data });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  };


 _displayAllData = () => {
    // console.log(this.state.data.length);
    // console.log(this.state.data);

    this.state.data.length &&
    this.state.data.map(el => {

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{el.name}</Text>
          <Text>{el.street}</Text>
          <Text>{el.postalCode}</Text>
          <Text>{el.city}</Text>
          <Text>{el.phone}</Text>
          <Text>{el.email}</Text>
          <Text>{el.nip}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

and then while rendering my content i try

```
        {this._displayAllData()}
```

Comment: You need to `return this.stata.data.map`

Comment: then i got error: "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently  your `_displayAllData` method is not returning anything. You need to return the map result in order to have some JSX returned by your method.

```
 _displayAllData = () => {


    // console.log(this.state.data.length);
    // console.log(this.state.data);

    return this.state.data.length &&
    this.state.data.map(el => {

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{el.name}</Text>
          <Text>{el.street}</Text>
          <Text>{el.postalCode}</Text>
          <Text>{el.city}</Text>
          <Text>{el.phone}</Text>
          <Text>{el.email}</Text>
          <Text>{el.nip}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, well I added this return statement but then i got error "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component."
It works! i just had to delete "this.state.data.length &&"  expression! Thanks dude, I was fighting with it for hours yesterday:) Could you only explain me why it doesnt want to work if i add  "return this.state.data.length &&"?

Comment: The thing is that when `this.state.data.length` equals to 0 then your method `_displayAllData` returns 0. It seems that you can only render those things in a Text component. A work around could be `return this.state.data.length ? this.state.data.map... : null;`

Comment: hmm ok now when you said so and I think about it, it's quite logical... Thank you mate, now I get it!